# How to improve performance on Mysql table - index, clustering, PK?

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key

I have a mysql table that stores status information about our users on a per-minute basis, but inserts have started taking up to 30 seconds to complete - we're still in private beta with only a couple of dozen users, but need to be able to handle thousands.

Usage info:

- Inserts: A new row is inserted about once per minute, per user
- Updates: Every few minutes the last few rows will be updated with revised data, per user
- Deletes: Entries more than 6 months ago are deleted once a day
- Selects: Only about 10 selects a day, per user (some select all rows per user for the day, some only get the most recent row for the user.)
- We're using AWS RDS, if that affects anything (Mysql 5.5.27)

This is the table definition that I've inherited:

```
CREATE TABLE statusMonitor (
  personId          int(10) unsigned  NOT NULL,
  monitorDateTime   datetime          NOT NULL,
/*
Other columns
*/
  UNIQUE KEY UQIX_statusMonitor (personId,monitorDateTime) USING BTREE,
  KEY personId (personId,monitorDateTime/* other cols */)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**I have three changes in mind, am I on the right track with these?**

1. **InnoDB** would be a better choice than MyISAM for a high-write table.
2. I'm thinking that doing the index based on the **date first** will be more efficient
3. A **primary key** would cluster the data making lookups faster, and inserts would be physically closer together.

So this would be my new definition:

```
CREATE TABLE statusMonitor (
  personId          int(10) unsigned  NOT NULL,
  monitorDateTime   datetime          NOT NULL,
/*
Other columns
*/
  PRIMARY KEY (
      monitorDateTime,
      personId
  ),
  UQIX_statusMonitor (monitorDateTime,personId) USING BTREE,
  KEY personId (monitorDateTime,personId/* other cols */)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Because we have fairly few users I can afford to break things for a little while by changing the table definition, but would rather get it right the first time, so it only happens once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnoDB` will be good if you have a lot of inserts, because each of those locks the whole table in case of `MyISAM`, and only a row in case of `InnoDB`.
You may consider vertical and/or horizontal partitions as well. 
Careful with KEYs, too many of those can slow down requests.